# Beaglebone black crashing when GPIO toggles for ultrasonic

Tags: sensor, gpio, ultrasound, beaglebone-black, beagleboard

I have written a simple program to toggle two GPIO pins (for TOGGLE and ECHO) as required for getting range measurements from a `HC-SR04` ultrasonic sensor. The program abruptly leads to increase in CPU usage (as seen by `top`) and the SSH connection is finally broken.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TRIGGER 48 // P9_15
#define ECHO 51    // P9_16

typedef enum direction {in, out} Direction;
typedef enum value {LOW=0, HIGH=1} Value;

double log_time(struct timeval tv){
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    double begin =
    (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000 ;
    return begin;
}

void SetDirection(int GPIO, Direction dir)
{
    char filename[36];
    FILE *fp;
    
    snprintf(filename,sizeof(filename),"/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction",GPIO);
    fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    switch (dir) {
    case in: fprintf(fp,"in\n"); break;
    case out: fprintf(fp,"out\n"); break;
    }
    close(fp);
}

void WriteGPIO(int GPIO, Value v)
{
    char filename[32];
    FILE *fp;
    
    snprintf(filename,sizeof(filename),"/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value",GPIO);
    fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",(int) v);
    close(fp);
}

Value ReadGPIO(int GPIO)
{
    char filename[32];
    FILE *fp;
    Value v;
    
    snprintf(filename,sizeof(filename),"/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value",GPIO);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d",(int *)&v);
    close(fp);
    return (v);
}

int main()
{
    int echoVal;
    struct timeval  tv;
    
    //SetDirection(LED,out);
    WriteGPIO(ECHO,LOW); /* Led on */ 
    sleep(2);
    // Trigger
    system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio60/value");
    // Poll for Echo pin
    double begin = log_time(tv);
    echoVal = LOW;
    while(echoVal!=HIGH)
    {
        echoVal = ReadGPIO(ECHO);
        sleep(0.01);
    }
        
    
    printf("Execution time %f\n", log_time(tv) - begin);

// if (ReadGPIO(SWITCH) == HIGH) {
//     /* switch input is high ... */
// }
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the reason for the crash? I have observed same thing when toggling the pins using `Python3`.

Comment: the argument to sleep is an integer so sleep(0.01) is sleep(0) and the compiler should tell you this with a warning

Comment: Is that a potential reason for the CPU usage peaking ?

Comment: @user253751 can you submit this as an answer? Would like to accept it and close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to sleep is an integer, so `sleep(0.01)` is actually just `sleep(0)` and the compiler should tell you this with a warning.

`sleep(0)` sleeps for no time at all, so the computer runs your loop as fast as possible.

To sleep for less than one second on Linux, use `usleep` or `nanosleep`.