# Why does the CPU usage of a Beaglebone Black peak while running an infinite loop?

Tags: cpu, beaglebone-black, sleep

I am using a BeagleBone Black to trigger an ultrasonic sensor and expecting the Echo pin-connected GPIO to be sensed as HIGH by my program, but it almost crashes the system.

```
while(1)
    {
    // Reset
    system("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value");printf(ret); 

    // Trigger
    system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value");
    usleep(10); // 10us
    system("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value");

     // read value
     result = read(pollfds[0].fd, readBuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
     if (result > 0){
            // read data ... do something
     }
     else{
            // do something else
    }

    usleep(1000*10); // sleep for 5ms
    }
}
```

On running it, the CPU usage spikes all the way from 3% to 72% and above. I noticed that significantly increasing the delay (`usleep()`) solves the problem but I can't afford delay more than a few ms.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of the device?

Comment: That's not an electronics question. Your PC also consumes a lot of power running an infinite loop of polling for data without any breaks sleeping between calls.

Comment: An infinite loop with no delays operates the cpu continuously. The printf command current draw depends on hardware connected but usually should not add significantly to the current drain. Low current sleep obviously reduced mean current. Removing the printf may help.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to do a realtime task on a non-realtime system. If the device runs a multitasking OS it can't guarantee it will run your code with timing you want, if what you want is just polling GPIO in a loop.

Comment: @Justme I am not looking for real-time performance but a decent polling system (that I plan to replicate for multiple pins on the same board). I don't think polling should be a troublesome task for such a device.

Comment: @PeDro - Hi, This question looks like the next stage of your investigation of [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638207/beaglebone-black-crashing-when-gpio-toggles-for-ultrasonic). Leaving that one open would risk people wasting time on *that* one, if (as it seems) you have moved on. Please (quickly) explain why that one should not be closed, to avoid duplication of effort, now that you have asked this one? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson the question was solved by the first comment (indicating the issue with `sleep()`. So it can be closed but I don't know how.

Comment: System() creates an entire shell and asks it to execute your command in my understanding. This is very costly for what amount to simple file io. Open that file for writing inside your program and see if the load goes down.

Comment: @PeDro - Hi, In that case, please write a comment back to that user (user253751) below their comment on your previous question, inviting them to make that into an answer. Then you can áccept it to effectively close that one. If they don't respond after a day or two, please write your own answer, copy their comment into it, add a credit to the original comment and accept your own answer to effectively close that one. That's how you can close that previous question. Thanks

Comment: The CPU of your board has only 1 CPU core. And it is running a multitasking Linux OS. It will have to go do other stuff more impotant than run a GPIO polling. Network, USB, etc handling. It will be difficult to get even moderate results. It is more troublesome than what you think.

Comment: I have a similar issue when emulating singlechip micros under Windows or Linux - cpu usage goes to max which is somewhat obvious. You have to throttle the loop. The Beaglebone has two PRU coprocessors that can handle the real time stuff or plug an Arduino in via USB.

Comment: "but I can't afford delay more than a few ms."  Yes, you are running a real-time system.  Having a do-not-exceed requirement on delay is the _definition_ of a real time system.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the select() or poll() or epoll() calls. Those calls allow you to wait for data to be ready on a file description with a timeout.

Comment: I have tried that but the values are no longer read after the first time. See the issue explained better here (https://forum.beagleboard.org/t/poll-a-gpio-pin-with-no-blocking/32998). I see no other option other than reopening the file descriptor every time.

Comment: just edited the question based on latest observations

Comment: Try something like in this module: https://github.com/mkaczanowski/BeagleBoneBlack-GPIO/ Apparently there are additional paths like ".../edge" you can use. Look at the waitForEdge method.

Answer (score 1):

The function system() is very inefficient, open the device file directly and write to it instead.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
int fh=open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value",O_WRONLY);
if(fh < 0) 
  perror("open fail");
else if ( write(fh,"0\n",2) < 2 )
  perror("write 0 fail");

usleep(10); // 10us
if(fh > 0) 
  IF (lseek(fh,0,SEEK_SET) < 0 ); // not sure if this is needed
    perror("lseek not work");

if(fh < 0) 
  perror("open fail");
else if ( write(fh,"1\n",2) < 2 )
  perror("write 1 fail");

write(fh,"0\n",2);
close(fh);
```

lseek above may not be needed. or you may need to instead close and reopen he device.

further

```
printf(ret);
```

Is almost certainly wrong , especially if user or system data is ever part of ret.`"100%no"`

Comment: Compiling it and running gives `write 0 fail:Invalid argument`

Comment: @PeDro they meant 1\n instead of 1/n

Comment: By the way: this method is faster than `system` but still has a bunch of overhead between your program and the pin. If this is still too slow, then maybe using Linux isn't the best option.

Comment: mmap() if it works here would be faster,  but direct file manipulation is an easy first step.